# python dataframe : delete rows with missing foreign keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I want to clean my main dataframe and remove rows with foreign keys missing from their main dataframes, for example :

DF A :

| idB | idC | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | Three |
| 2 | 5 | Three |
| 3 | 6 | Three |

DF B :

| idB | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Two | Three |
| 7 | Two | Three |

DF  C :

| idC | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Two | Three |
| 6 | Two | Three |

final DF A :

| idB | idC | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 6 | Three |

first row of DF A should be deleted because idB = 1 doesnt exist in DF B

Second row of DF A should be deleted because idC = 5 doesnt exist in DF C

Third row of DF A should be kept idB = 3 exists in DF B and  idC = 6 exists in DF  C

how to do that please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df_a[df_a.idB.isin(df_b.idB) & df_a.idC.isin(df_c.idC)]
```

Output:

```
>>> df_a[df_a.idB.isin(df_b.idB) & df_a.idC.isin(df_c.idC)]
    idB  idC   age
2    3    6  Three
```